# How to create a split Office ribbon button like Text Fill

Tags: user-interface, vsto, ms-office, ribbon

I would like to create a ribbon button in Microsoft Office that reproduces the behavior e.g. of the "Text Fill" button. It is split in two areas where the left (red) will execute the default/last action and the right (blue) offers additional functions.

[image: TextFill]

The closest I got was using a `splitButton` with a `button` and a `menu`. But here a get a large button with text for the default action and only a small area with a triangle for accessing the drop-down menu. Here are the ribbon code and the resulting button:

```
<splitButton id="SplitButton1" size="normal" >
  <button id="MenuButton1" imageMso="TextFillColorPicker" label="Text Fill" />
  <menu id="Menu1" label="Label1" itemSize="normal" showLabel="true">
    <button id="MenuButton2" label="Label2" />
  </menu>
</splitButton>
```

[image]

For usability reasons I would like to keep the (visual) focus on the drop-down part exactly as shown in the image. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your need is to exactly reproduce the original button in your Ribbon, you can use this code :

```
<control idMso="FontColorPicker" imageMso="FontColorPicker"/>
```

(I have looked around to find this and I couldn't find any info, so I figured out it could be useful to someone one day)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's only 2 options for ControlSize proeprty, either Regular or Large. So just use the Regular size, and add an image to your split button.

Please refer to this API for more details:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonsplitbutton.controlsize

An example for Custom UI with Ribbon XML

```
<splitButton id="splitButton"> 
     <button id="splitButton__btn" imageMso="AlignLeft" label="SplitButton" onAction="splitButton_Click" /> 
     <menu id="splitButton__mnu"> 
     <button id="btnAlignLeft" imageMso="AlignLeft" onAction="btnAlign_Click" label="Left" /> 
      </menu> 
</splitButton>
```

Ribbon XML on MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327872

Perhaps you might want to try `<MenuSection>` tag

```
<MenuSection
 DisplayMode=["Default" | "Small" | "Medium"  | "Large"  | "Text"  | "Menu"  | "Menu16"  | "Menu32"  | "Thin"]
 Id="String"
 MaxHeight="String"
 Scrollable="true"
 Sequence="Integer"
 Title="String">
 [<Controls /> | <Gallery />]
</MenuSection>
```

Seems that you could define different types of display mode.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334378.aspx

Comment: I don't really think it's about the control size. Please see the screenshot that I just added which shows the control I get.

Comment: I think you might have to go with customize UI by using Ribbon XML. My post updated with a bit example.

Comment: This seems to be close to the approach that I used which led me to the result that's not quite matching what I am trying to achieve. Maybe I don't understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do what you want, due to customization limitations... But you can try defining a box instead of a splitButton:

```
<box id="BoxSplit" boxStyle="horizontal">
  <button id="MenuButton1" imageMso="TextFillColorPicker" />
  <menu id="Menu1" label="Text Fill" itemSize="normal" showLabel="true">
    <button id="MenuButton2" label="Label2" />
  </menu>
</box>
```

This gives you the following result:

[image: box with button and menu, hovering button]

[image: box with button and menu, hovering button]

As you see, the problem is now that the menu and the button are not highlighted together. I hope this is acceptable for you...

Answer (score -1):

When declaring the splitButton, set the size attribute to "small"

Comment: When I tried this Visual Studio would tell me "The 'size' attribute is invalid" (only "normal" and "large" are allowed) and my ribbon did not load at all.